# How to change my directory root in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I'm using XAMPP and my root is C:/xampp/htdocs. Firstly, I will list my files:

I have index.php file on htdocs/public
I have theme.css file on htdocs/public/css

I'm trying to link my css file to my html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```

But it doesn't work. When I right click to the browser and select "view source", and when I click to the href="/css/theme.css", it goes to this direction: 
http://localhost:8080/css/theme.css

But I want to make it go to this direction:
http://localhost:8080/public/css/theme.css

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to indicate your current directory to include the css file, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```

Here, `./` indicates the current directory.

**Or**, you can specify the file path relative to the root directory like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```

**Or**, you can just remove this `/public/` altogether and include your css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/theme.css" type="text/css">
```